# Java String wrong order concatenation of different languages

Tags: java, string, unicode, concatenation

[image: Screen Shoot of strange java String behavior]

So, as you can see from the image, that i have concatenated a,c and b. And i am getting the result i expected.
But in 2nd println, when i concatenated a,e and b, i got e concatenated in the end, not where i was expecting it to be.
I want to know, the reason of this behavior and solution to this behavior.
Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
public class prob 
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        String a="الف",b="1/2",c="ب",e="B";

        System.out.println(a+" : "+c+" : "+b);
        System.out.println(a+" : "+e+" : "+b);
    }
}
```

EDIT(To explain why my question is not a duplicate):
My question is on converting L2R languages to R2L.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29672273/3459206

Comment: "as you can see from the image". There *are* blind people reading this website. They can't read images. However if you copied & pasted the code/output as text (in code blocks) they would be able to hear it.

Comment: I have pasted the code for any reason one might need, you can compile and READ output yourself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because the first character is R2L (right to left orientation as in asian languages), so next character becames at the begining (correct orientation):

First char:

```
الف 
// actual orientation ←
```

Second char added at L

```
// add ←
B : الف 
// actual orientation →
```

After this, B is L2R as usual in Europe, so next char (1/2) is added in the right orientation AFTER B:

```
// → add in this direction
B : 1/2 : الف 
// actual orientation → (still)
```

---

You can easily test it by copy paste char and writting manually another, you will see how orientation changes depending of the char you inserted.

---

**UPDATE:**

> what is my solution for this issue, because i made this example only to show what issue i was facing in making some big reports, where data is mix sometimes, it is L2R String and sometimes R2L. And i want to make a string in strictly this format.(

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255490/3850595):

> - Left-to-right embedding (U+202A)
> - Right-to-left embedding (U+202B)
> - Pop directional formatting (U+202C)
>
> So in java, to embed a RTL language like Arabic in an LTR language like English, you would do

```
myEnglishString + "\u202B" + myArabicString + "\u202C" + moreEnglish
```

> and to do the reverse

```
myArabicString + "\u202A" + myEnglishString + "\u202C" + moreArabic
```

> See (for the source material)
>
> - [Bidirectional General Formatting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Bidirectional_General_Formatting) for more details,
> - [the Unicode specification chapter on "Directional Formatting Codes"](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Embedding)

---

**ADD ON 2:**

```
char l2R = '\u202A';
System.out.println(l2R + a + " : " + e +" : "+b);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
‪الف : B : 1/2
```

Comment: So, what is my solution for this issue, because i made this example only to show what issue i was facing in making some big reports, where data is mix sometimes, it is L2R String and sometimes R2L.
And i want to make a string in strictly this format.(Which will than be used in further report making)

Comment: changing to
System.out.println(a+" : "+"\u202A"+e+"\u202A"+" : "+b);
also has no effect. I am not getting what i am missing here

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal kindly check again my last add-on, you have to think about result and how it will affect to text, but it's not hard... just play around a bit... ;)

Comment: Thankyou very much for you help.

Comment: And sorry if i was about to annoy you :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason, as it's said already in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33218444/4053652), is the fact that some string have a right-to-left orientation.

You can manually set the orientation to letf-to-right for the string with right-to-left orientation, with `\u200e` control `character`, like:

```
String a="\u200eالف",b="1/2",c="\u200eب",e="B";

System.out.println(a+" : "+c+" : "+b);
System.out.println(a+" : "+e+" : "+b);
```

Comment: I tried it but i am not getting desired output with
System.out.println(a+" : "+("\u200e"+e)+" : "+b);
and
System.out.println(a+" : "+"\u200e"+e+" : "+b);
Why i am settign it in the function has a reason, that this is just an example program to explain the behaviour, which i was facing in an application where i need to make and store(for later printing usage) Strings which can contain either L2R or R2L strings, and i need to concat them in correct order

Comment: this wont work because is not a concatenation of strings, so orientation changes wont affect

Comment: So, i need to use concat funtion?

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal you have to modify not the e vatiable, but other variables like System.out.println("\u200e"+a+" : "+e+" : "+"\u200e"+b);
e is already has a l2r orientation or a whole string  System.out.println("\u200e"+a+" : "+e+" : "+b);

Comment: This reverses whole of my string concatination order.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal you just have to provide the order you neede with adding `\u200e` l2r and `\u202e` r2l formatting as you need it.

Comment: @JordiCastilla this changes the r2l orientation of all r2l-orientated strings to l2r, that means, all the strings now are l2r-orientated and that won't cause any problems with orientation. why do you suppose, you have to use concatenation?

Comment: To differenciate special char from string content

Comment: @JordiCastilla agree, that it could look more obviously. But to use concatenation in case, you create a new fixed string is a little bit expensive sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the other answers but nothing worked for me. Instead of the concatenation of strings, I used the StringBuilder class.

```
StringBuilder append = new StringBuilder(" Leftover").append('\u202A').append("الضريبة").append('\u202C').append("Thermalization");
```