# DecimalFormat returns weird Character when formatting negative double

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting, left-to-right

i have a simple program that calculates a double value and prints it.
whenever the value of that double is negative the first character of the outputted string is \u200e,
ASCII value 8206.
i cannot find anything about this online.

```
        System.out.println((int)DecimalFormat.getInstance().format(-1).charAt(0));
        System.out.println((int)DecimalFormat.getInstance().format(-1.0).charAt(0));
        System.out.println((int)NumberFormat.getInstance().format(1).charAt(0));
        System.out.println((int)NumberFormat.getInstance().format(0).charAt(0));
```

it prints as follows:

8206 
8206 
49 
48

so i know that every negative value is given this weird prefix, but why?
if i use `String.format()` it doesn't happen.
no found documentation on this anywhere.

Anyone encountered this or knows how to explain?

Comment: I suspect you’ll get different results if you use `getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Answer (score 0):

You format a number into String, then take a first character `charAt(0)`, cast it to `int` and actually print the ASCII code.

So it's no wonder that the code may produce a result like this:

```
45  // ASCII code of - in your default locale it's another character for negative values
45
49  // ASCII code of 1
48  // ASCII code of 0
```

[8206](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) is a Unicode character for [left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark).

It is very likely that this character is added to the `NumberFormat` / `DecimalFormat` to properly display values left-to-right when an RTL locale is applied as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672273/13279831)

Comment: The issue is i am manipulating strings and that value (8206) comes out of nowhere. there is also a char value for '-' so that's not the problem. the problem is an extra char that does nothing for the display of the string, rather just disrupts its reading.

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible with default `en_US` locale as well as with any available locale including those with right-to-left orientation.  Can you provide any details about your locale settings?